# Win2k8R2 is not showing file/product version info of .so files

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I am not able to see the product/file version information, copyright information of ".so" files in Win2k8-R2. I am logged in as administrator. If i rename the same file to have it extension to some other ie. ".dll" or ".txt", then i am able to see all the information (file/version info, copyright info).

Is it expected for Win2k8-R2. Is it documented somewhere??

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design.  The "property page" code (that fills the contents of the "details" page of a given file type) is registered by file extension.

Try cloning the registry entry for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.dll such that HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.so has the same registry key values.

Start regedit.
Locate HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dll
Export this entire registry key to a disk file (so.reg)
Edit the so.reg file with notepad.
Rename all the registry key path references to "\.dll" to "\.so"
Keep the "dllfile" reference the same
Save so.reg.
Double click on so.reg so as to register it. (Say yes to all the prompts)

Close all the open explorer windows and then re-open the one that has the .so file in it.
Right-click on the .so file.  You should see the details page and all DLL version information inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have two queries: 1. Is it documented somewhere? 2. I tried steps mentioned by you (exporting .dll registry keys to .so) but it doesn't seem to work. Is there anything else that i need to do?

Comment: 1) It is documented in MSDN.  2) The registry key hack worked for me on Windows 7.  You may have to reboot for it to take effect.